# Add Object to Specific json PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have been looking for a while how to add this two objects to inside DATA of my json call.

i have try this

```
$signer = array(
    'signatures' => array('some data'),
    'pubkeys' => array('some data'),
   );

array_push($result, $signer);
```

and the output is this. allways put  thath two value in the begining of json squeleton. but i need put thath two values inside DATA SECTION

```
    {
    "0": {
        "signatures": [
            "some data"
        ],
        "pubkeys": [
            "some data"
        ]
    },
    "data": {
        "tx": {
            "block_height": -1,
            "block_index": -1,
            "hash": "69da371cacae35ae1c8426f09e51a028d820480551fa3c0821e6e1615883307e",
            "addresses": [
                "Xe747jtZwNWh8ZadnYKfYKZbzwDMA9zTJ1"
            ],
            "total": 20740200,
            "fees": 13700,
            "size": 119,
            "preference": "high",
            "relayed_by": "108.175.3.18",
            "received": "2018-11-26T12:24:41.152398845Z",
            "ver": 1,
            "double_spend": false,
            "vin_sz": 1,
            "vout_sz": 2,
            "confirmations": 0,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "prev_hash": "37120cd926d45499cc334e6915d3421ec244189f99575a38a3f7d63aa04c821e",
                    "output_index": 1,
                    "output_value": 20753900,
                    "sequence": 4294967295,
                    "addresses": [
                        "Xe747jtZwNWh8ZadnYKfYKZbzwDMA9zTJ1"
                    ],
                    "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash",
                    "age": 976367
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "value": 20703900,
                    "script": "76a914257c9d647a3d522e1eaeb61df272fb3918f375b288ac",
                    "addresses": [
                        "Xe747jtZwNWh8ZadnYKfYKZbzwDMA9zTJ1"
                    ],
                    "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash"
                },
                {
                    "value": 36300,
                    "script": "76a914257c9d647a3d522e1eaeb61df272fb3918f375b288ac",
                    "addresses": [
                        "Xe747jtZwNWh8ZadnYKfYKZbzwDMA9zTJ1"
                    ],
                    "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash"
                }
            ]
        },
        "tosign": [
            "966c044f9c21f94f9708914540053015646bb216918ec31ffc874ab8785a222b"
        ]
    }
}
```

the call should be seen as follows. signatures and pubkey should add inside DATA. the structure would look like this.

data
    tx
    tosign
    signatures
    pubkey

```
{ so this is the code with (signatures and pubkeys values)
"data": {
    "tx": {
        "block_height": -1,
        "block_index": -1,
        "hash": "69da371cacae35ae1c8426f09e51a028d820480551fa3c0821e6e1615883307e",
        "addresses": [
            "Xe747jtZwNWh8ZadnYKfYKZbzwDMA9zTJ1"
        ],
        "total": 20740200,
        "fees": 13700,
        "size": 119,
        "preference": "high",
        "relayed_by": "208.135.6.59",
        "received": "2018-11-26T11:47:58.079469294Z",
        "ver": 1,
        "double_spend": false,
        "vin_sz": 1,
        "vout_sz": 2,
        "confirmations": 0,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "prev_hash": "37120cd926d45499cc334e6915d3421ec244189f99575a38a3f7d63aa04c821e",
                "output_index": 1,
                "output_value": 20753900,
                "sequence": 4294967295,
                "addresses": [
                    "Xe747jtZwNWh8ZadnYKfYKZbzwDMA9zTJ1"
                ],
                "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash",
                "age": 976367
            }
        ],
        "outputs": [
            {
                "value": 20703900,
                "script": "76a914257c9d647a3d522e1eaeb61df272fb3918f375b288ac",
                "addresses": [
                    "Xe747jtZwNWh8ZadnYKfYKZbzwDMA9zTJ1"
                ],
                "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash"
            },
            {
                "value": 36300,
                "script": "76a914257c9d647a3d522e1eaeb61df272fb3918f375b288ac",
                "addresses": [
                    "Xe747jtZwNWh8ZadnYKfYKZbzwDMA9zTJ1"
                ],
                "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash"
            }
        ]
    },
    "tosign": [
        "966c044f9c21f94f9708914540053015646bb216918ec31ffc874ab8785a222b"
    ],
    "signatures": [
        "sadasd"
    ],
    "pubkeys": [
        "0327d5d59731a19b0d4b00ffc50582572a4c3f6ad6887cf4af6b21b39fbe3ff5a4"
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!. Please show your attempt so that we can help

Comment: and why javascript tag is here? do you want to do it in javascript?if yes then why php tag?

Comment: please check the post again. i  update it. i use php